# Export data with css to excel

Tags: javascript, css, excel, export-to-excel

I have an action which takes JSON data and converts it to table in html with tr , td etc.

Is there a way I can add a css code to design some parts of my table or is the only way is to append to the elements as an attribute?

Comment: While you generate html table add necessary classes and style it with css. Basic stuff.

Comment: title got me excited for a moment..  i thought you could now export data to excel using CSS only